# How to use client side scripts with customValidators?

Tags: asp.net

If I leave the checkbox blank and click the submit button, nothing happens. If I check it and hit the submit button, nothing happens.

The javascript fires, I just don't know why no text is displayed and the page doesn't postback.

```
        function ValidateCheckBox(source, args) {
          args.IsValid = document.getElementById('<%= cb_confirmation.ClientID%>');
        }
```

Here is the validator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="cb_Validator" 
        OnServerValidate="CheckBoxRequired_ServerValidate"
        CssClass="errorMessage" Display="Static" ErrorMessage="You must select this box to confirm"
        Text="***" ClientValidationFunction="ValidateCheckBox">
        </asp:CustomValidator>
```

The checkbox:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="cb_confirmation" runat="server" />
```

And the button that causes validation is

```
<asp:Button ID="btn_submit" runat="server" Text="Submit" CausesValidation="true" 
            CssClass="submitButton" onclick="btn_submit_Click"/>
```

EDIT: The solution was to add a ".checked" to the end of the javascript function.

Comment: Are you sure some other validator isn't setting `args.IsValid` to `false`? Alternately, maybe the client-side validation engine is checking whether `args.IsValid === true` - you're setting it to a DOM element, not a boolean value.

Comment: Thank you. The solution was adding ".checked" to the line in the javascript function.